# RESOLVED : find({user: {user: admin}}) doesn't works on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a little API and I want when I login the API recover a users profiles with only the username my Schema looks like this (I use Mongoose) :

```
user : {
  username: String,
  password: String
}
```

but when I try to execute :

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
User.find({user: {username: "test"})
```

It doesn't work !
I try this :

```
User.find({_id: "id")
```

and works ! I don't understand !

Help me please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to look for a value.

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uVz_mvOUkQj) example where query works perfectly

```
db.collection.find({
  "user.username": "test"
})
```

And, why using the object doesn't work? Because mongo tries to look for the entire object to be equal.

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oHvx18p4gaB) example where using the object the document is found (because all properties are used in the query)